# After upgrade CiviCRM 5.28 to 5.32.2. Cron is Stop When Mailing start

Tags: mailing, cron-job, civicrm-home, scheduled-job

After Upgrade CiviCRM version 5.28 to 5.32.2. Cron stops when mass mailing start.
After mass mailing completed Cron is again start.
CiviCRM: 5.32.2
Drupal: 7
Php: 7.2.24

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem is here ... is it now showing that cron is running ok ?

Comment: @Aidan , Cron is running OK But When Mailing is start running Cron stops and CiviCRM is showing "Cron Not Running" notification. It is happened only during mailing running time

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM keeps track of `cron` by looking at the "Upgrade Check" job and requires it to have run within the last hour. If the "Upgrade Check" job is set to "every hour" perhaps your mailing delays that a bit?